# Chaves duplicadas

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

** Melhorando o Post para melhor entendimento do ocorrido. 
Pessoa, boa tarde.

Eu criei uma tabela 'cliente' no sql server e coloquei o campo e-mail como vachar(50), unique e aceita null

pq pela lógica, não existe 2 e-mails iguais...
Só que agora quando eu vou fazer um insert no banco e o valor do e-mail é null ele me retorna falando que não posso ter essa chave duplicada.

> "Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ__CLIENTE__161CF72400F78D67'.
>   Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.CLIENTE'. The duplicate key
>   value is (). The statement has been terminated."

Como que eu privo para não deixar e-mails "validos" cadastrar duplicado e aceitar mais de 1 cliente com email = null?

Exemplificando o problema.

## Criado a tabela

`CREATE TABLE TEST(
ID_TEST INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
NOME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
EMAIL VARCHAR(20) 
PRIMARY KEY(ID_TEST),
constraint VALOR_NULO UNIQUE(EMAIL)
)`

## Depois insiro meu primeiro valor com o campo de e-mail nulo

`INSERT INTO TEST
VALUES('LUIZ', NULL)`

## Depois tento o segundo valor:

`INSERT INTO TEST
VALUES('JUCA', NULL)`

Quando eu tento inserir este valor que ele me acusa que os valores chaves não pode ser duplicado, não pode ter 2 valores(por que está com a constraint 'unique')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você deve ter criado a tabela com a declaração do email assim:

`email varchar(max) unique`

Coloquei `max` apenas como exemplo. Isso vai gerar uma *constraint* que não permitirá valores duplicados, incluindo `null`.

Como você marcou a tag `sql-server-2012`, para versão você tem uma alternativa (da versão 2008 em diante na verdade):

- Remova o `unique` da coluna email;
- Crie um índice `unique` que aceite nulls, assim:

  CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_clienteemail
     ON cliente(email) WHERE email IS NOT NULL

Isso vai validar o valor único para email e vai permitir nulos.

Comment: Ricardo, deu certo! 
Isso mesmo que precisava! 
vlw pela ajuda!

Answer (score 3):

Na criação do índice deve usar esta cláusula:

```
WHERE email IS NOT NULL;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Create/NotNull.sql).

Comment: Opa, vlw acho que agora deu